# Responsive design with emphasis on retina display and desktop. Sprites and JS: what to sacrifice?

Tags: html, css, web-applications, retina-display

I'll try to sum this up as best as possible. I'm developing a web application which needs to be:

- Responsive, with emphasis in desktop and iPhone (retina display)
- Supportive of all modern browsers plus ie8 and ie9
- Server-efficient, meaning: as little JS and as many icons inside a sprite as possible

**Targeting device width/height vs Targeting pixel ratio:**

For the conditional **CSS**, I went for targeting pixel ratio instead of creating different layouts for specific platforms and devices or using the safari user agent. So I'm using `@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)` plus all my responsive styles.

Now I'm trying to decide how to deal with the **images**.

**Two images for each background vs One image with background-resize**

Because I want to keep the server request as fewer as possible, I'm using sprites (4 or 5 "stencils") instead of separate pngs (the SVG discussion is another thing!). But `Background-size` is NOT supported by IE8, a big portion of my users, so it needs a JS fallback like [jquery.backgroundSize.js](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.backgroundSize.js).

So:

> **Is the combination of sprites, conditional background-size and a JS fallback for IE8 the best option, from a performance and good-practise point of view?**

I didn't find other questions with this specific (yet quite common nowadays) scenario. It's not intended as a discussion question, I'm more interested in knowing if there is an actual agreement on how to deal with the situation: Retina display, sprites, IE and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conditional `background-size` would not be the preferred option.** If you chose to use the property to use hi-res sprites for clients with "normal" pixel ratio, you'd end up with lower image quality than that of a pre-rendered image, additional computational overhead for the client to scale the graphic and transferring ~4 times larger sprites than needed. By *relying* on `background-size` you also end up artificially limiting your site's compatibility with legacy browsers, while an IE8 JS fallback is also likely to introduce content flicker (whether or not acceptable in your scenario).

I'd go with pre-rendered versions per pixel ratio (so you effectively end up with twice the image files). You'd be able to provide the user with better quality graphics than `background-size` ever could. If you build sprites manually (as opposed to generating them and accompanying css with an automated tool), this would introduce maintenance overhead but the solution would be overall preferable.

1. Make a high-dpi version of your css file e.g. *main-highdpi.css* and <del>conditionally</del> include it with an appropriate media query not unlike `<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" type="text/css" href="main-highdpi.css" />`
2. Create hi-res versions of sprites you rely on and update css sprite references. I don't believe the preferred naming convention is agreed on yet (postfixing the resource name with `@2x` seems popular e.g. *main.png & main@2x.png*)
3. Profit!

I would advocate such an approach because of the higher rendering quality of raster images (as opposed to scaling with `background-size`), lack of compatibility issues and faster client-side rendering. The downside is transferring bigger image files which is an acceptable price to get a hi-res image onto the client device (and the sprites will be cached anyway). At least you do not end up requesting both copies as [this article suggests](http://phatness.com/2012/07/css-image-replacement-for-high-dpi-retina-display/)!

Just be sure to keep in mind individual device limitations (image size and dimentions etc.).

Comment: It didn't occur to me that background-size would render badly in the main browsers. Is that the case?

Comment: @yisela: unless I misunderstood your question, you intended to downsample a high-res image with background-size? e.g. have a high-res 600x200 logo fit into a real rendering space of 300x100. It all depends on the client-side algorithm but imo it's safe to assume the quality will be lower than that of a pre-rendered image, plus it adds computational overhead for the client to resize it. You also end up transferring sprites that are ~4 times bigger than you need

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right. Only downside is having to prepare the images (and any eventual edits) twice, but it's not big deal. Would you still consider this the best practise for a site with, say, more than 50 or 100 images?

Comment: Doesn't really matter imo (so, still "yes" for 100+ images), however you may want to invest some time into setting up proper automation. Depending on how source graphics is stored, you could use photoshop javascript to create different versions of the same sprite etc.

Answer (score 0):

My website is mostly content and some very basic scripting, so I chose to embed all my javascript in the page and avoid external scripts (jquery, etc) since they have a significant impact on page load times.

I also chose to prefer the high res images as the default, if the default is the wrong image, some will be downloaded twice. Bandwidth is most critical on a mobile device, so high res should be the default, and low res being activated later.

I also favoured simplicity over choosing the best image in all situations because, frankly, most visitors will not even notice the difference. It's not a disaster for the wrong one to show up.

And finally, I wanted it to use the new `srcset` draft standard that appears to be the long term solution to this problem, even though it hasn't been implemented yet.

So, I use an image tag, with `src` for high res, and `srcset` for low res:

```
<img src="foo.png" srcset="foo-low.png 1x" width="42" height="42">
```

Then with javascript I process all image tags. I chose inline javascript right before `</body>` rather than a `domready` event to improve page load speed - we want the browser to know the correct image URLs as soon as possible, every millisecond counts in this case.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function swapRetinaImagesOut() {
        // skip anything with a "retina" screen
        if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1)
          return;

        // check if the browser appears to support the "srcset" attribute
        if (typeof(document.createElement('img').srcset) != "undefined")
          return;

        // find all images with an "srcset" property, and swap them
        var imageEls = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i = 0; i < imageEls.length; i++) {
          var imageEl = imageEls[i];
          var srcset = imageEl.getAttribute('srcset');
          if (!srcset)
            continue;

          imageEl.src = srcset.match(/^[^ ]+/)[0];
        }
      }

      swapRetinaImagesOut();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's simple but effective, I look forward to improvements anybody can contribute.